# This app is no longer compatible with your device

Tags: android, google-play, firemonkey

I have uploaded my first app to the Google Play Store which was compiled using the latest Rad Studio Rio Version (10.3.2). When using one of the tablets I testes the app with the Play Console app says:

> Your Device isn't compatible with this version

The app is designed to run on tablets but will work on phones. When using Play Console (via Web) I'm told that the App isn't compatible with some of my devices, specifically the very same tablets I have been using to test the app.

I've followed the guide [from here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play).

How might I move this forward?

This is the app manifest as generated for me by RAD studio

```
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->``
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="%package%"
        android:versionCode="%versionCode%"
        android:versionName="%versionName%"
        android:installLocation="%installLocation%">

    <!-- This is the platform API where NativeActivity was introduced. -->
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="%minSdkVersion%" android:targetSdkVersion="%targetSdkVersion%" />
<%uses-permission%>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="True"/>
    <application android:persistent="%persistent%" 
        android:restoreAnyVersion="%restoreAnyVersion%" 
        android:label="%label%" 
        android:debuggable="%debuggable%" 
        android:largeHeap="%largeHeap%"
        android:icon="%icon%"
        android:theme="%theme%"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="%hardwareAccelerated%">

<%application-meta-data%>
        <%services%>
        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
                android:label="%activityLabel%"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="%libNameValue%" />
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <%activity%>
        <%receivers%>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: @rimonmostafiz: editing feedback. There's no need to embolden software names by default - folks can read them just fine, and excessive levels of emboldening makes a post less readable. Bold should be used sparingly in technical writing. Also, if you see an error message or something that is not in the voice of the question author, a quote block is most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Ok answering my own question here. I wasn't aware that Google console will display a list of incompatible devices for your app. If you select one it will display the item(s) which are causing the incompatibility. In my case (although I can't remember selecting it because my app doesn't need it) was telephony.